# How to write PopupMenu in Kotlin in RecycleViwer?

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, android-recyclerview

This is first time that i am creating Andorid app so please help, so i have this code in my adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.setOnClickListener {
            d("daniel", "clicked")
        }

        holder.view.img_more.setOnClickListener{
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, it)
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when(item.itemId){
                    R.id.action_settings ->{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"this is toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.action_settings ->{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"this is toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_prijem_posiljke)
            popupMenu.show()
        }
    }
```

In the line:

```
val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, it)
```

for "this" context says required context. What do i need to put there for this to work?
thank you

Comment: Rather than `this` you can use `holder.view.context`.

Comment: Thank you, you kind man, thank you sooo much

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Every View object in Android has an associated context which is the Activity or Fragment class which instantiated the view. You can use the context property of the view to gain a context but you need to be careful not to leak it. If you really need a context, you can pass `applicationContext` as a dependency to the `Adapter` class. But as a quick solution you can replace your code with the following as suggested by @Jeel and it should work.

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.view.setOnClickListener {
        d("daniel", "clicked")
    }

    holder.view.img_more.setOnClickListener{
        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(holder.view.context, it)
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
            when(item.itemId){
                R.id.action_settings ->{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"this is toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_settings ->{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"this is toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_prijem_posiljke)
        popupMenu.show()
    }
}
```